# keytool -genkey error: Keystore file does not exist

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, keytool

I try to create a new self certified keystore file

The command I use is:

```
keytool -genkey -selfcert -dname "cn=My Name, ou=Orga unit" -alias selfcertified -keypass somepass -keystore keystore.jks -storepass anotherpass -validity 365
```

but I always get this annoying error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: keystore.jks
```

I do not understand why I'm getting this error. The command above should create a new keystore, so why is it complaining about a non existing store?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Generating a key pair (and a new keystore) has to be done as a separate operation to creating a self-signed certificate for that key.

i.e.

```
keytool -genkey -alias myKey -keystore store.jks
keytool -selfcert -alias myKey -keystore store.jks
```

Comment: from the keytool online documentation: A keystore is created whenever you use a -genkey, -import, or -identitydb command to add data to a keystore that doesn't yet exist. (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/solaris/keytool.html). according to this, the keytool command should create a new keystore instead of saying it does not exist. could you plz give an example of how to perform these two steps you mentioned?

Comment: @Chris Friedl - `-genkey` and `-selfcert` are separate commands: you can't do both at once.

Comment: thanks! - two separate commands did it finally. the funny thing is, there are several sites providing tutorials with the two commands in one line as i have written above.

Comment: It says store file not found? what is store.jks here?

Answer (score 3):

Run command prompt as Administrator and it will be done.

Answer (score 2):

First generate the upload key using below command:

```
keytool -genkeypair -v -keystore my-upload-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

then run

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v
```

Answer (score 0):

**-selfcert** option was made obsolete in keytool for Java 6. Check the last section of "Changes" here: [Java 6 Keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html)

So for Java 6 and onwards, replace **-selfcert** with **-certreq**

Answer (score 0):

Seems a old link but this is what I tried - Hope this helps someone.
In my case as .keystore file was missing in the below location, I had run the following command;
keytool -genkey -alias mykey -keystore "C:\Users\username.keystore"
This creates a .keystore file in the location, system asks you for information like
What is your first and last name?
What is the name of your organizational unit?
What is the name of your organization?
What is the name of your City or Locality?
What is the name of your State or Province?
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
Is CN=XXX, OU=XXX, O=XXX, L=XXX, ST=XXX, C=IN correct?

Say "Yes" and the keystore will get created.