# Error when exporting .apk from Eclipse / Android Developer Tools

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk, adt

Every time I try to export the project I get the error:

android keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Key pair not generated, alias already exists

- I tried making a new key and using my old key - neither work
- I've tried saving it in a different location - even created new folders to ensure there were no conflicts
- tried filling out all new credentials when creating the key - same error:

"android keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Key pair not generated, alias already exists"

Comment: how do you export the project? never seen that before... but found that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4920072/944070

Comment: Have you solved this problem..? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is the building .apk not success. May be file name in drawable is invalid..etc..

try **Export an unsigned APK** and sign it manually in

```
appManifest.XML > design> export
```

Fix all errors can occur.

Then you can export apk use key normal.

Hope this help!