# keystore generation for tomcat

Tags: java, https, tomcat8

*trying to generate keystore using:*
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin$ keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore /home/ubuntu/techstack/tomcatkeyfiles

then it asked me to enter org details and at the end, it's throwing this error:

keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ubuntu/techstack/tomcatkeyfiles (Is a directory)

Comment: `-keystore` should be a file, not a directory

Comment: generated without -keystore flag, its showing me this:keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Key pair not generated, alias <tomcat> already exists. where can i find already generated file. iam using ubuntu 18.04 machine

Comment: ["the default keystore file named .keystore is created in the user's home directory if it doesn’t already exist"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/keytool.html)

Comment: See also: [keytool -genkey error: Keystore file does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4920072/476716)

Comment: @OrangeDog Thank so much for the information. I will check it